# no suitable conversion function from "const DListNode" to "DListNode *" exists for doubly linked list copy constructor

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor, doubly-linked-list

I am currently working on writing a copy constructor/assignment operator for a doubly linked list class and having issues.

DoublyLinkedList.h

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class DoublyLinkedList; // class declaration

// list node
class DListNode {
private: int obj;
  DListNode *prev, *next;
  friend class DoublyLinkedList;
public:
  DListNode(int e=0, DListNode *p = NULL, DListNode *n = NULL)
    : obj(e), prev(p), next(n) {}
  int getElem() const { return obj; }
  DListNode * getNext() const { return next; }
  DListNode * getPrev() const { return prev; }
};

// doubly linked list
class DoublyLinkedList {
protected: DListNode header, trailer;
public:
  DoublyLinkedList() : header(0), trailer(0) // constructor
  { header.next = &trailer; trailer.prev = &header; }
  DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList& dll); // copy constructor
  ~DoublyLinkedList(); // destructor
  DoublyLinkedList& operator=(const DoublyLinkedList& dll); // assignment operator
  // return the pointer to the first node
  DListNode *getFirst() const { return header.next; } 
  // return the pointer to the trailer
  const DListNode *getAfterLast() const { return &trailer; }
  // return if the list is empty
  bool isEmpty() const { return header.next == &trailer; }
  int first() const; // return the first object
  int last() const; // return the last object
  void insertFirst(int newobj); // insert to the first of the list
  int removeFirst(); // remove the first node
  void insertLast(int newobj); // insert to the last of the list
  int removeLast(); // remove the last node
};
// output operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const DoublyLinkedList& dll);
```

This was a supplementary header file where the node and linked list classes are both declared. I have noticed that the protected class members of DoublyLinkedList (header and trailer) are not DListNode pointers, but actual DListNode values; more on that in a bit.

My copy constructor in DoublyLinkedList.cpp

```
DoublyLinkedList::DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList& dll)
{
  // Initialize the list
  header.next = &trailer; trailer.prev = &header;
  DListNode* iter = dll.header; // PROBLEM LINE
  if (this != &dll) {
      while (iter != nullptr) {
          insertLast(iter->obj);
          iter = iter->next;
      }
  }
}
```

I have tried solving the problem many different ways, with and without editing the header file. I can't change header and trailer to DListNode* as they are not allowed to be changed, and changing iter to a non-pointer would mean I can't traverse the linked list; so I am now at an impasse. Because I can't change the datatypes of the operands, I'm not sure what to do to fix the error. I thought it may have something to do with dll being passed as constant reference, but even fiddling around with that didn't do much. I have been looking at this for a couple hours and just can't seem to get it to work. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: What about 'DListNode const* iter = &dll.header;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list has two cells to manage even if it is empty.
You could adopt a different design choice with

```
class DoublyLinkedList {
protected:
  DListNode *header;
public:
  DoublyLinkedList() : header(nullptr) {} // constructor
  ...
  bool isEmpty() const { return header == nullptr; }
  void insertLast(int val)
     {  if (header == nullptr) {
            header = new DListNode(val);
            header->next = header->prev = header;
        }
        else {
            header->prev->next = new DListNode(val, header->prev, header);
            header->prev = header->prev->next;
        }
     }
};
```

Nevertheless, with your design choice (one empty cell at the beginning and one empty cell at the end), you can define your copy constructor as

```
DoublyLinkedList::DoublyLinkedList(const DoublyLinkedList& dll)
{
  // Initialize the list
  header.next = &trailer; trailer.prev = &header;
  if (this != &dll) {
      DListNode* iter = dll.header.next;
      while (iter != &dll.trailer) { // no insertion if dll is empty
          insertLast(iter->obj);
          iter = iter->next;
      }
  }
}
```

You should draw your data structure before and after each operation to be sure of how your algorithm works.

You can also implement an invariant (method `bool isValid() const`) to verify the chaining between cells: `cell->next->prev` should be `cell` except for the last empty node and `cell->prev->next` should be `cell` except for the first empty node.

Comment: Ah I see. In my intro programming course my prof taught linked lists as the header and trailer pointing to the first and last node of the list respectively, and I mistakenly assumed it was so here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This list looks a little different than the usual doubly linked list implementations but it can work.

From the code you've shown it looks like the two non-pointer members, `header` and `trailer`, are used only to keep track of the two ends of the list but are not actually part of the list. This is supported by a few things from the code fragment above:

- an empty list has `header` and `trailer` pointing to each other, with no values set for these two nodes and no other nodes between them
- `getFirst()`, which according to the comment above it should return a pointer to the first node, actually returns the node after `header` and not `header` itself
- you have a `getAfterLast()` function that judging by it's name should return a marker after the last node in the list, and which returns `trailer`.

If the above is correct and `header` and `trailer` are not actually part of the list, then your implementation of the copy constructor is wrong. It should only copy the actual value nodes from the input list, excluding the header and trailer. This means you copy node values from nodes starting with `getFirst()` and stop when reaching `getAfterLast()`.

Something like this in code:

```
if (this != &dll) {
    const DListNode* iter = dll.getFirst();
    while (iter != dll.getAfterLast()) {
        insertLast(iter->obj);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}
```

Note that this also handles graciously the case when the source list is empty. If `dll` is empty, `dll.getFirst()` will actually return the trailer, which is also what `getAfterLast()` returns. So the `while` loop will not be executed, the list will remain empty.